# Why the compile line is wrong which makes it not able to find the header file

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have the following make file:

```
######## Intel(R) SGX SDK Settings ########
SGX_SDK ?= /opt/intel/sgxsdk
SGX_MODE ?= SIM
SGX_ARCH ?= x64
UNTRUSTED_DIR=untrusted
M_BED=mbedtls_SGX-2.6.0    
########################### NOTE M_BED variable

ifeq ($(shell getconf LONG_BIT), 32)
    SGX_ARCH := x86
else ifeq ($(findstring -m32, $(CXXFLAGS)), -m32)
    SGX_ARCH := x86
endif

ifeq ($(SGX_ARCH), x86)
    SGX_COMMON_CFLAGS := -m32
    SGX_LIBRARY_PATH := $(SGX_SDK)/lib
    SGX_ENCLAVE_SIGNER := $(SGX_SDK)/bin/x86/sgx_sign
    SGX_EDGER8R := $(SGX_SDK)/bin/x86/sgx_edger8r
else
    SGX_COMMON_CFLAGS := -m64
    SGX_LIBRARY_PATH := $(SGX_SDK)/lib64
    SGX_ENCLAVE_SIGNER := $(SGX_SDK)/bin/x64/sgx_sign
    SGX_EDGER8R := $(SGX_SDK)/bin/x64/sgx_edger8r
endif

ifeq ($(SGX_DEBUG), 1)
ifeq ($(SGX_PRERELEASE), 1)
$(error Cannot set SGX_DEBUG and SGX_PRERELEASE at the same time!!)
endif
endif

ifeq ($(SGX_DEBUG), 1)
        SGX_COMMON_CFLAGS += -O0 -g
else
        SGX_COMMON_CFLAGS += -O2
endif

######## App Settings ########

ifneq ($(SGX_MODE), HW)
    Urts_Library_Name := sgx_urts_sim
else
    Urts_Library_Name := sgx_urts
endif

# App_Cpp_Files := App/App.cpp $(wildcard App/Edger8rSyntax/*.cpp) $(wildcard App/TrustedLibrary/*.cpp)
App_Cpp_Files := $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/m_server.cpp $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/Utils.cpp \
    $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/manager.cpp $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/linear_regression.cpp \
    $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/fileUtility.cpp $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/dbHandler.cpp \
    $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/naive_bayes.cpp
    
App_C_Files := $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/mbedtls_net.c $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/mbedtls_error.c
App_Include_Paths := -IInclude -I$(UNTRUSTED_DIR) -I$(SGX_SDK)/include -I$(M_BED)/include -I/usr/include/mysql

########################### NOTE M_BED include path

App_C_Flags := $(SGX_COMMON_CFLAGS) -fPIC -Wno-attributes $(App_Include_Paths)

########################### NOTE here

# Three configuration modes - Debug, prerelease, release
#   Debug - Macro DEBUG enabled.
#   Prerelease - Macro NDEBUG and EDEBUG enabled.
#   Release - Macro NDEBUG enabled.
ifeq ($(SGX_DEBUG), 1)
        App_C_Flags += -DDEBUG -UNDEBUG -UEDEBUG
else ifeq ($(SGX_PRERELEASE), 1)
        App_C_Flags += -DNDEBUG -DEDEBUG -UDEBUG
else
        App_C_Flags += -DNDEBUG -UEDEBUG -UDEBUG
endif

App_Cpp_Flags := $(App_C_Flags) -std=c++11
App_Link_Flags := $(SGX_COMMON_CFLAGS) -L$(SGX_LIBRARY_PATH) -L$(M_BED)/lib -l$(Urts_Library_Name) -lmbedtls_SGX_u -lpthread -lmysqlclient



ifneq ($(SGX_MODE), HW)
    App_Link_Flags += -lsgx_uae_service_sim
else
    App_Link_Flags += -lsgx_uae_service
endif

App_Cpp_Objects := $(App_Cpp_Files:.cpp=.o)
App_C_Objects := $(App_C_Files:.c=.o)



ifeq ($(SGX_MODE), HW)
ifneq ($(SGX_DEBUG), 1)
ifneq ($(SGX_PRERELEASE), 1)
Build_Mode = HW_RELEASE
endif
endif
endif


.PHONY: all run

ifeq ($(Build_Mode), HW_RELEASE)
all: osn_server
    @echo "Build osn_server [$(Build_Mode)|$(SGX_ARCH)] success!"
    @echo
    @echo "*********************************************************************************************************************************************************"
    @echo "PLEASE NOTE: In this mode, please sign the enclave.so first using Two Step Sign mechanism before you run the app to launch and access the enclave."
    @echo "*********************************************************************************************************************************************************"
    @echo


else
all: osn_server
endif

run: all
ifneq ($(Build_Mode), HW_RELEASE)
    @$(CURDIR)/osn_server
    @echo "RUN  =>  osn_server [$(SGX_MODE)|$(SGX_ARCH), OK]"
endif

######## App Objects ########

$(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/enclave_u.c: $(SGX_EDGER8R) trusted/enclave.edl
    @cd $(UNTRUSTED_DIR) && $(SGX_EDGER8R) --untrusted ../trusted/enclave.edl --search-path ../trusted --search-path $(SGX_SDK)/include
    @echo "GEN  =>  $@"

$(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/enclave_u.o: $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/enclave_u.c
    @$(CC) $(App_C_Flags) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "CC   <=  $<"


$(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/%.o: $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/%.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(App_Cpp_Flags) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "CXX  <=  $<"

########################### NOTE above

osn_server: $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/enclave_u.o $(App_Cpp_Objects) $(App_C_Objects)
    @$(CXX) $^ -o $@ $(App_Link_Flags)
    @echo "LINK =>  $@"



.PHONY: clean

clean:
    @rm -f osn_server  $(App_Cpp_Objects) $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/enclave_u.* $(App_C_Objects)
```

My directory structure look like this

```
├── common
│   ├── base64.h
│   ├── ml_struct.h
│   ├── network_ra.h
│   ├── remote_attestation_result.h
│   └── ssl_context.h
├── Makefile
├── mbedtls_SGX-2.6.0
│   ├── include
│   │   └── mbedtls
│   │       ├── aes.h
│   │       ├── aesni.h
│   │       ├── arc4.h
│   │       ├── asn1.h
│   │       ├── asn1write.h
│   │       ├── base64.h
│   │       ├── bignum.h
│   │       ├── blowfish.h
│   │       ├── bn_mul.h
│   │       ├── camellia.h
│   │       ├── ccm.h
│   │       ├── certs.h
│   │       ├── check_config.h
│   │       ├── cipher.h
│   │       ├── cipher_internal.h
│   │       ├── cmac.h
│   │       ├── compat-1.3.h
│   │       ├── config.h
│   │       ├── ctr_drbg.h
│   │       ├── debug.h
│   │       ├── des.h
│   │       ├── dhm.h
│   │       ├── ecdh.h
│   │       ├── ecdsa.h
│   │       ├── ecjpake.h
│   │       ├── ecp.h
│   │       ├── ecp_internal.h
│   │       ├── entropy.h
│   │       ├── entropy_poll.h
│   │       ├── error.h
│   │       ├── gcm.h
│   │       ├── glue.h
│   │       ├── havege.h
│   │       ├── hmac_drbg.h
│   │       ├── md2.h
│   │       ├── md4.h
│   │       ├── md5.h
│   │       ├── md.h
│   │       ├── md_internal.h
│   │       ├── memory_buffer_alloc.h
│   │       ├── net.h
│   │       ├── net_sockets.h
│   │       ├── oid.h
│   │       ├── padlock.h
│   │       ├── pem.h
│   │       ├── pkcs11.h
│   │       ├── pkcs12.h
│   │       ├── pkcs5.h
│   │       ├── pk.h
│   │       ├── pk_internal.h
│   │       ├── platform.h
│   │       ├── platform_time.h
│   │       ├── ripemd160.h
│   │       ├── rsa.h
│   │       ├── sha1.h
│   │       ├── sha256.h
│   │       ├── sha512.h
│   │       ├── ssl_cache.h
│   │       ├── ssl_ciphersuites.h
│   │       ├── ssl_cookie.h
│   │       ├── ssl.h
│   │       ├── ssl_internal.h
│   │       ├── ssl_ticket.h
│   │       ├── threading.h
│   │       ├── timing.h
│   │       ├── version.h
│   │       ├── x509_crl.h
│   │       ├── x509_crt.h
│   │       ├── x509_csr.h
│   │       ├── x509.h
│   │       └── xtea.h
│   └── lib
│       ├── libmbedtls_SGX_t.a
│       ├── libmbedtls_SGX_u.a
│       └── mbedtls_SGX.edl
├── metadata.txt
├── sgx_t.mk
├── sgx_u.mk
├── third_party
│   ├── rapidjson
│   │   ├── allocators.h
│   │   ├── document.h
│   │   ├── encodedstream.h
│   │   ├── encodings.h
│   │   ├── error
│   │   │   ├── en.h
│   │   │   └── error.h
│   │   ├── filereadstream.h
│   │   ├── filewritestream.h
│   │   ├── fwd.h
│   │   ├── internal
│   │   │   ├── biginteger.h
│   │   │   ├── diyfp.h
│   │   │   ├── dtoa.h
│   │   │   ├── ieee754.h
│   │   │   ├── itoa.h
│   │   │   ├── meta.h
│   │   │   ├── pow10.h
│   │   │   ├── regex.h
│   │   │   ├── stack.h
│   │   │   ├── strfunc.h
│   │   │   ├── strtod.h
│   │   │   └── swap.h
│   │   ├── istreamwrapper.h
│   │   ├── memorybuffer.h
│   │   ├── memorystream.h
│   │   ├── msinttypes
│   │   │   ├── inttypes.h
│   │   │   └── stdint.h
│   │   ├── ostreamwrapper.h
│   │   ├── pointer.h
│   │   ├── prettywriter.h
│   │   ├── rapidjson.h
│   │   ├── reader.h
│   │   ├── schema.h
│   │   ├── stream.h
│   │   ├── stringbuffer.h
│   │   └── writer.h
│   └── single_include
│       └── nlohmann
│           └── json.hpp
├── trusted
│   ├── ca_bundle.h
│   ├── check.cpp
│   ├── dtree.h
│   ├── ecalls.cpp
│   ├── e_engine.cpp
│   ├── e_engine.h
│   ├── encdec.cpp
│   ├── encdec.h
│   ├── enc.h
│   ├── enclave.config.xml
│   ├── enclave.edl
│   ├── enclave.h
│   ├── enclave.lds
│   ├── enclave_private.pem
│   ├── Log.c
│   ├── Log.h
│   ├── pprint.c
│   ├── pprint.h
│   ├── sealunseal.cpp
│   ├── sealunseal.h
│   ├── ssl_conn_hdlr.cpp
│   ├── ssl_conn_hdlr.h
│   └── trusted_LR.h
└── untrusted
    ├── dbHandler.cpp
    ├── dbHandler.h
    ├── dbHandler.o
    ├── enclave_u.c
    ├── enclave_u.h
    ├── enclave_u.o
    ├── fileUtility.cpp
    ├── fileUtility.h
    ├── fileUtility.o
    ├── globals.h
    ├── linear_regression.cpp
    ├── linear_regression.h
    ├── linear_regression.o
    ├── manager.cpp
    ├── manager.o
    ├── mbedtls_error.c
    ├── mbedtls_net.c
    ├── m_server.cpp
    ├── m_server.o
    ├── naive_bayes.cpp
    ├── naive_bayes.h
    ├── naive_bayes.o
    ├── sample_messages.h
    ├── Utils.cpp
    ├── Utils.h
    └── Utils.o
```

when I try to build it fails with the error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/intel/thesis/code/osn_server/sgx/enclave_enclave'
cc    -c -o untrusted/mbedtls_net.o untrusted/mbedtls_net.c
untrusted/mbedtls_net.c:24:25: fatal error: mbedtls/net.h: No such file or directory
```

I have no clue why mbedtls/net.h file is not found although it is present. Any solution or how could I try yo troubleshoot.

Comment: Well, it's pretty obvious if you look at your compiler command line: `cc -c -o untrusted/mbedtls_net.o untrusted/mbedtls_net.c`.  You haven't told the compiler where to find your headers.  Just because _you_ know where they are, doesn't tell the compiler where they are.

Comment: @MadScientist: But I have this line: @$(CC) $(App_C_Flags) -c $< -o $@ and App_C_Flags := $(SGX_COMMON_CFLAGS) -fPIC -Wno-attributes $(App_Include_Paths)

Comment: Sure.  But obviously that recipe is not being used, because you hide the command in your recipe using `@` (which you should **NEVER** do until your makefile works completely), but this compile line is printed.  So what I'm saying is that your statement of the problem is not correct: the reason why the header file is not found is obvious: it's because your compile line is wrong.  The real question is, why is your compile line wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in rule for compiling .c files to .o files uses `$(CFLAGS)`, not `$(App_C_Flags)`.

Is it possible that the rule

```
$(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/enclave_u.o: $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/enclave_u.c
```

was actually supposed to be generalized like so:

```
$(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/%.o: $(UNTRUSTED_DIR)/%.c
    @$(CC) $(App_C_Flags) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "CC   <=  $<"
```

That would make it work for all files in the `untrusted` directory.
Alternatively you could set `CFLAGS=$(App_C_Flags)`